# SQL: count 1 in a given month if a count > 1 exists previously

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following data in a Postgres table named `orders`:

```
month_year  order_id    customer_id
2016-04     0001        24662
2016-05     0002        24662
2016-05     0002        24662
2016-07     0003        24662
2016-07     0003        24662
2016-07     0004        24662
2016-07     0004        24662
2016-08     0005        24662
2016-08     0006        24662
2016-08     0007        24662
2016-08     0008        24662
2016-08     0009        24662
2016-08     0010        11372
2016-08     0011        11372
2016-09     0012        24662
2016-10     0013        24662
2016-10     0014        11372
2016-11     0015        24662
2016-11     0016        11372
2016-12     0017        11372
2017-01     0018        11372
2017-01     0019        11372
```

SQL fiddle at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/4efe6/1.

I'd like to be able to count the number of "repeat customers" per month.  We can define "repeat" as a customer having ***EVER*** placed an order (whether it was last month or years ago).

For example, customer `24662` placed his first order in April 2016.  Therefore, in any subsequent month, if customer `24662` places another order, then he will get a 1 count ***in that month***.

I tried with the following:

```
SELECT        
    month_year, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT(customer_id))
FROM 
    orders

GROUP BY 
    month_year

HAVING 
    COUNT(order_id) > 1
```

Which gives:

```
month_year   repeat_orders
2016-05      1
2016-07      1
2016-08      2
2016-10      2
2016-11      2
2017-01      1
```

But, because of the `GROUP BY`, this is only applying the 1 count based on the whether a customer had more than 1 order ***in a given month***, not whether he/she EVER had a previous order.

I'm looking for the latter, and would expect to see the following:

```
month_year     repeat_orders
2016-05        1
2016-07        1
2016-08        1
2016-09        1
2016-10        2
2016-11        2
2016-12        1
2017-01        1
```

Any assistance would be most appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Self join usually performs poorly.

You can use a window function `FIRST_VALUE` to get the first date when the customer appeared in the data and scan the table only once. After that simply compare the current date with the first date to see if this is a repeat customer or not.

**Preliminary query:**

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
  SELECT
    *
    ,FIRST_VALUE(month_year) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY month_year) AS first_date
  FROM
    orders
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  CTE
ORDER BY
  customer_id
  ,month_year
  ,order_id
;
```

This produces the following results:

```
| month_year | order_id | customer_id | first_date |
|------------|----------|-------------|------------|
|    2016-08 |     0010 |       11372 |    2016-08 |
|    2016-08 |     0011 |       11372 |    2016-08 |
|    2016-10 |     0014 |       11372 |    2016-08 |
|    2016-11 |     0016 |       11372 |    2016-08 |
|    2016-12 |     0017 |       11372 |    2016-08 |
|    2017-01 |     0018 |       11372 |    2016-08 |
|    2017-01 |     0019 |       11372 |    2016-08 |
|    2016-04 |     0001 |       24662 |    2016-04 |
|    2016-05 |     0002 |       24662 |    2016-04 |
|    2016-05 |     0002 |       24662 |    2016-04 |
|    2016-07 |     0003 |       24662 |    2016-04 |
|    2016-07 |     0003 |       24662 |    2016-04 |
|    2016-07 |     0004 |       24662 |    2016-04 |
|    2016-07 |     0004 |       24662 |    2016-04 |
|    2016-08 |     0005 |       24662 |    2016-04 |
|    2016-08 |     0006 |       24662 |    2016-04 |
|    2016-08 |     0007 |       24662 |    2016-04 |
|    2016-08 |     0008 |       24662 |    2016-04 |
|    2016-08 |     0009 |       24662 |    2016-04 |
|    2016-09 |     0012 |       24662 |    2016-04 |
|    2016-10 |     0013 |       24662 |    2016-04 |
|    2016-11 |     0015 |       24662 |    2016-04 |
```

**Final query**

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
  SELECT
    *
    ,FIRST_VALUE(month_year) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY month_year) AS first_date
  FROM
    orders
)
SELECT
  month_year
  ,COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN month_year > first_date THEN customer_id END) AS repeat_orders
  ,COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN month_year = first_date THEN customer_id END) AS first_orders
FROM
  CTE
GROUP BY
  month_year
ORDER BY
  month_year
;
```

This query produces the following result:

```
| month_year | repeat_orders | first_orders |
|------------|---------------|--------------|
|    2016-04 |             0 |            1 |
|    2016-05 |             1 |            0 |
|    2016-07 |             1 |            0 |
|    2016-08 |             1 |            1 |
|    2016-09 |             1 |            0 |
|    2016-10 |             2 |            0 |
|    2016-11 |             2 |            0 |
|    2016-12 |             1 |            0 |
|    2017-01 |             1 |            0 |
```

**Performance**

If you create an index on `(customer_id, month_year)` you should eliminate a sort in the query plan (i.e. it will run faster).

Answer (score 1):

I think the query will look something like:

```
SELECT 
 o1.month_year, 
 count(distinct o1.customer_id) 
from orders o1
left join 
 orders o2 on o1.customer_id = o2.customer_id
  and o1.month_year > o2.month_year
   and o1.order_id != o2.order_id
where o2.order_id is not null
group by month_year
```

It's starts similar to what you've done. We're just adding a self join to the orders table to find if the customer being evaluated placed an order in any month before. We're also making sure that the order_id doesn't match because i saw some duplicates in the data. This produces the expected results

Hope it makes sense. Let me know if you have any follow up would be happy to help

**Edit**

Based on the comment that "first time customer" info may be required too I think we can use a [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) here

```
with first_customers as (
  select 
    customer_id,
    min(month_year) month_year
  from orders
  group by customer_id
), repeat_customers as (
  select distinct on (o.order_id)
    o.customer_id,
    o.month_year
  from orders o
  join first_customers fc on o.customer_id = fc.customer_id and o.month_year > fc.month_year
) select 
    o.month_year, 
    count(distinct fc.customer_id) first_customers, 
    count(distinct rc.customer_id) repeat_customers 
  from orders o
    left join first_customers fc on o.month_year = fc.month_year
    left join repeat_customers rc on o.month_year = rc.month_year
  group by o.month_year
  order by o.month_year
```

Essentially we find the first time customers by grouping orders data by customer_id and fetch the row with the min month_year

The logic for finding repeat_customers goes in its respective cte as well. It's a bit simplified now because we can use the information from first_customers to see if the customer ever ordered before

In the final select, we query orders table and join on both the ctes and count their distinct customer_ids by month

Comment: this works great!  Thank you.  How would I add a column to represent the number of "first time customers" who place an order in a given month?

Comment: Hmm the approaches that come to my mind include using Common Table Expression (CTE) or Union. I have edited my answer to include first time customers using CTE. Let me know what you think

Comment: Note I have assumed that a first time customer is someone who has placed an order for the first time ever. Is this what you meant as well?

Comment: @NikhilSatiani, window functions make these kind of queries simpler and faster. In your last query the engine will scan the table at least three times. Have a look at my answer to see how they can be applied here.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov Totally agreed your solution is much more efficient - learnt a lot from it! Didn't know we had a window function FIRST_VALUE. Thanks a lot for sharing that